# Using cmd commands in java to print a file

Tags: java, cmd

Im trying to print a notepad file from my java swing application. 
However i can't seem to get it to work.

When i type in this command in the command prompt, it prints the given notepad file.
 `start /min notepad /p C:\score-programma\boem.txt`

however when i try to do this in java, it says the file cannot be found.

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "start": CreateProcess error=2, Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at nl.daalhuisen.model.Model.print(Model.java:184)
    at Apl$1$1.actionPerformed(Apl.java:86)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 41 more`

this is the java code i run:

`String[] args = {"start", "/min", "notepad", "/p", "C:\score-programma\boem.txt"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);`

i have also tried 


`String[] args = {"cmd.exe", "start", "/min", "notepad", "/p", "C:\score-programma\boem.txt"};`

This does not generate the same error, but nothing happens. 
What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start` is a built-in command to `cmd`. it's not an executable. you'd have to run:

```
cmd /c start notepad /p c:\etc...
```

the `/c` flag is necessary to tell `cmd` that you're trying to run some OTHER program. If you don't pass that in, then `start`, `notepad`, etc.. will be treated as arguments to cmd itself.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use something like the code below .. and do some Java research for adding "minimized" settings

```
package com.example.command;

import java.io.*;

public class JavaRunCommand {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String command = "notepad /p ";
        String filepath = "C:\\Temp\\readme.txt";
        String s = null;

        try {
            // using the Runtime exec method:
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command + filepath);
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getErrorStream()));

            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            // read any errors from the attempted command
            System.out
                    .println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception happened - here&#39;s what I know: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```